# Create a new repository/branch using bzrlib

Tags: bazaar, bzrlib

I'm trying to programmatically create a new blank Bazaar branch/repo, tantamount to running `brz init`. I've tried several different routes from the [bzrlib documentation](http://people.canonical.com/~mwh/bzrlibapi) but so far haven't succeeded.

These failures are listed below:

```
from bzrlib import repository
r = repository.Repository.open('/tmp/testing')
r = repository.Repository.create('/tmp/testing')

from bzrlib import branch
b = branch.Branch.create('/tmp/testing')
b = branch.Branch.open('/tmp/testing')
```

All result in failures that `/tmp/testing` is not a branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nice convenience function hidden in there somewhere:

```
from bzrlib import bzrdir
bzrdir.BzrDir.create_branch_convenience('./foo')
```

> Create a new ControlDir, Branch and Repository at the url 'base'.
>
> This is a convenience function - it will use an existing repository if
>   possible, can be told explicitly whether to create a working tree or
>   not.
>
> This will use the current default ControlDirFormat unless one is

I honestly don't remember how I found it. Probably by reading the code of a plugin.